# Unknown Action rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having this really strange issue with my routes in rails.

I am getting the following error:

`Unknown action The action 'blah_sdk' could not be found for AdminController`

This is happening when a button is pressed on the web page. The button code is here and is located in `BlahBase/index.html.erb`:

`<div id="sdk_metrics"><%= button_to "Click me", {:action =>:view_sdk_data, :method => :get} %></div>`

I have a `BlahBaseController` that doesn't have a `:view_sdk_data` action. The `BlahBaseController` header looks like the following:

`class Admin::BlahBaseController < AdminController`

I do have a `BlahSdkController` that is a subclass of `Admin::BlahBaseController` which has a `view_sdk_data` action like so:

```
class Admin::BlahSdkController < Admin::BlahBaseController

  def view_sdk_data
    #do something
  end
end
```

But for some reason rails keeps trying to look in the `AdminController` and I'm not sure why. Any ideas?

Edit:
Also this is what my routes file looks like

```
resources :blah_sdk do
  collection do
    get :view_sdk_data
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

if your BlahBase controller renders the index action on which you have the `{:action => :view_sdk_data}` link... then url_for (which generates your urls vis routing) will assume that  you still want the same controller (ie `BlahBase` not `BlahSdk`).

if you want another controller, you have to tell it eg use : `{:action => :view_sdk_data, :controller => :blah_sdk}`

Comment: Yeah I don't think that is the issue because even when I go to the URL   that the button is supposed to go to I get the same message, so I don't think it's an issue with the button.

Comment: What happens when you run `rake routes` in the terminal? can you edit your question and add the relevant routes?

Answer (score 0):

**Route**

My immediate recommendation would be to add a [namespace](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing), or scope to your routes:

```
#config/routes.rb
namespace :admin do
    resources :blah_sdk do
        collection do
           get :view_sdk_data
        end
    end
end
```

--

**Path Helper**

My second recommendation would be to use the actual path helper, rather than just referencing the `action`. This not only keeps your code much `DRYer`, but also ensures you're sending to the correct path / action every single time.

I would therefore do something like this:

```
<%= button_to "Test", admin_view_sdk_data_path %>
```

As a rule, it's *always* better to use the built-in helpers in Rails. It might sound lame, but you can rely on them to provide the correct functionality